# Button need to move to top of the soft key

Tags: android

I have a login screen as shown in the picture.

[image: screen]

[image: screen]

When the soft key comes it hides the Login button. I need the button moves to the top of the soft key so that the user can click after entering the id and password.

Below is the layout......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="50dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email_mob_edit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="E-MAIL"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_top_boarder"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#2c2a29"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:imeOptions="flagNavigateNext">
        </EditText>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/table_cell_seperator"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password_edit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword" 
            android:hint="PASSWORD"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#2c2a29"
            android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bottom"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/forgot_password_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="Glemt Password?"
        android:textColor="#ffff"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/invalid_alert_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Husk at udfylde e-mail/mobilnummer og password"
        android:visibility="invisible" 
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/login_xml"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: TRy reducing the padding from button.

Answer (score 0):

set softinputmode to adjustpan|adjust-resize by adding following line to activity tag:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

Comment: you have set your components placement by setting margin hardcoded into dip, instead use weight or relative layout to align your componenets